# How to deploy a nodejs app that uses python scripts on heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have a basic nodejs app that works fine on its own on heroku, but I want to add a python script that nodejs will call that uses a numpy package. I have gotten it to work on my local host but I am struggling to get it to work on heroku as it does not recognise the numpy package and I cannot seem to install it with pip as it does not get recognised either.

Comment: Have you tried installing it with `easy_install`?

Comment: No, I have not, how does that work?

Comment: The same as you would do it with `pip`. `easy_install numpy`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, only got "Error: Command failed: easy_install numpy
       /bin/sh: 1: easy_install: not found" when I tried to build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I had to do was add a requirements.txt file to my project and run: heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python -a appname